# Java ConcurrentHashMap atomic get if present

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

How do you perform a safe get if present operation on a Concurrent Hash Map? (same thing like putIfAbsent)

Bad example, not very thread safe (check then act situation):

```
ConcurrentMap<String, SomeObject> concMap = new ...

//... many putIfAbsent and remove operations

public boolean setOption(String id, Object option){
   SomeObject obj = concMap.get(id);

   if (obj != null){
      //what if this key has been removed from the map?
      obj.setOption(option);
      return true;
   }

   // in the meantime a putIfAbsent may have been called on the map and then this
   //setOption call is no longer correct

   return false;
}
```

Another bad example would be:

```
   public boolean setOption(String id, Object option){
       if (concMap.contains(id)){
           concMap.get(id).setOption(option);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

The desirable thing here is to not bottleneck the add, remove and get operations by synchronizing them.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "this setOption call" - which setOption method do you refer to? You have two in your code.

Comment: It's just a generic set method on some generic object that is stored in the map.

Comment: Your second example would be defective if key-value pairs might be removed from the map. That could happen between the contains test and the get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be trying to do is to lock a key over multiple operations. Only each operation is atomic. These is no simple way to lock a key, only to lock the map.

However in the "what if I delete a key" case, all you can do is to delay the delete operation until after the setOption is called.  The outcome should be the same.

You appear to be trying to solve a problem which may not need to be solved.  You haven't explained why calling setOption after a key is deleted or while a the key is waiting to be deleted is bad.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your reply, I have figured out my problem, it is just a modified case of the readers writers problem. Suppose I have a set of operations set1 = {op1, op2, op3 ...} that can be run in parallel, but whenever an operation in set2 = {opr1, opr2, ..} is run the eventual operations from set1 and the rest of the operations from set2 must wait.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I also have similar question on CHM [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135998/how-to-atomically-update-the-value-of-concurrentmap-in-multithreaded-application). I am trying to update the value of concurrenthashmap in thread safe and atomic way.

Answer (score 7):

The `get()` method on a `ConcurrentHashMap` is atomic. Since that map does not allow null values, `get()` implements "get if present": If the result is `null`, the key was not present.

Comment: But what if the get returned null because at the call time that key was not present, but between the get call and the test on it's return value that key was added to the map (from another thread, somewhere else in the code)?

Comment: The get does return null if that key is not present. But if it was added between the get and the null test?

Comment: The value returned would not change just because it changed in the map.

Comment: If you need this level of exclusivity, you need to lock a central object like the map itself though you would loose much of the benefit of using the ConcurrentMap.

Comment: There is no happens-before relation between the null test and the possible `putIfAbsent` in another thread. So where would be the difference between that other thread putting a value between `get` and the `null` test, and that other thread putting a value after your `setOption` returned `false`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `containsKey` / `get`, just call `get`. If that method returns `null` then the key was not present otherwise the key was present, and you got hold of the value that it was mapped to at the time of the `get`.

From the docs:

> *Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.*

This is how your second example should look:

```
public boolean setOption(String id, Object option) {

    SomeObject opt = concMap.get(id);
    if (opt == null)
        return false;

    opt.setOption(option);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But what if the get returned null because at the call time that key was not present, but between the get call and the test on it's return that key was added to the map (from another thread, somewhere else in the code)?

Comment: Would that be conceptually different from some other thread adding the key-value pair AFTER the null test?

Comment: What if the value is a Boolean? You can't compare a Boolean to null so you probably need to use containsKey.

Comment: @MikeStoddart sure you can compare `Boolean` to null.

Comment: Of course! I'm thinking of the boolean primitive. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do multiple operations on a single key in ConcurrentMap, you can use either  **Lock striping** technique to reduce contention, here's an example with Guava framework:

```
   private Striped<Lock> lock;
    public boolean setOption(String id, Object option) {
      try {
        Lock lock = concMap.get(id);
        lock.lock();
          if (concMap.contains(id)){
          concMap.get(id).setOption(option);
       return true;
   }
   return false;
        } finally {
         lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Or, since Java 8: ConcurrentMap.compute is a new atomic method, see how it is done on a key:

```
    concMap.compute(keyId, (key, value) -> {
    dosmth; ... return key;  });
```

p.s. Possible variations are with ConcurrentMap.computeIfPresent(), etc.