# How to atomically update the value of ConcurrentMap in multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap, atomic

I have a `ConcurrentMap` which I need to populate from multithread application. My map is shown below:

```
  private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> deviceErrorHolder = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
```

Below is my method which is called from multithreaded application at very fast rate so I need to make sure it is fast.

```
  public void addDeviceErrorStats(String deviceName, String errorName) {
    AtomicLongMap<String> errorMap = deviceErrorHolder.get(deviceName);
    if (errorMap == null) {
      errorMap = AtomicLongMap.create();
      AtomicLongMap<String> currenttErrorMap = deviceErrorHolder.putIfAbsent(deviceName, errorMap);
      if (currenttErrorMap != null) {
        errorMap = currenttErrorMap;
      }
    }
    errorMap.incrementAndGet(errorName);
  }
```

For each `deviceName`, I will have an `AtomicLongMap` which will contain all the counts for different `errorName`.

```
  ExceptionCounter.getInstance().addDeviceErrorStats("deviceA", "errorA");
  ExceptionCounter.getInstance().addDeviceErrorStats("deviceA", "errorB");
  ExceptionCounter.getInstance().addDeviceErrorStats("deviceA", "errorC");

  ExceptionCounter.getInstance().addDeviceErrorStats("deviceB", "errorA");
  ExceptionCounter.getInstance().addDeviceErrorStats("deviceB", "errorB");
```

Is my `addDeviceErrorStats` method thread safe? And also the way I am updating the value of my `deviceErrorHolder` map is correct? Meaning will it be an atomic operation? Do I need to synchronize creation of new `AtomicLongMap` instances? Or CM will take care that for me?

I am working with Java7.

Comment: why dont you write some test case to generate you scenario and share the result  :D

Comment: You need computeIfAbsent to make it thread safe.

Comment: I am still on Java 7 so cannot use `computeIfAbsent`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is there any problem with my code then? And  it is not thread safe?

Comment: @user5447339 the computeIfAbsent would be a one liner and currentErrorMap is the most recent to be created.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Apart from one line stuff, my code will still work fine right without any issues?

Comment: @user5447339 unless I missed something, yes but better to use the built in method to reduce any doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *lot* simpler version of this with `computeIfAbsent()`.

```
AtomicLongMap<String> errorMap = deviceErrorHolder.computeIfAbsent(deviceName, a -> AtomicLongMap.create());
errorMap.incrementAndGet(errorName);
```

The `computeIfAbsent` (in concurrent maps) is especially meant to do an atomic version of what your null checking logic does. If the `deviceName` key has a value, it's returned, otherwise the computation is called atomically, and the return value of the computation is both associated with the key in the map as well as returned.

Comment: What is the problem with my code? If there is a problem then what is the best way to do this in Java 7?

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Guess you'll have to tolerate the extra code and a few unnecessary object creations that your version has.

Comment: So my code is still fine? Bcoz as Peter mentioned that may be it is not thread safe?

Comment: Yeah, it just has the potential to create an extra object for each `deviceName`. There's no data loss potential or other problems with it.

Comment: Ok.. I was thinking on this, do you think If I use `LoadingCache` from guava then it can reduce this extra object creation? bcoz it can synchronize on the creation of new AtomicLongMap instances automatically? And yes I won't be using all the caching features.

Comment: It'll probably be a lot simpler than the piece of code you have. Simplicity is always good, performance can always be improved if deemed necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130585/discussion-between-user5447339-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your method is correct. Let's assume we have two concurrent threads calling it for the same device

The case where the errorMap already existed is trivial, as both threads will get the same and call `incrementAndGet` on it, which is atomic.

Let's now consider the case where errorMap didn't exist. say the first thread gets to `AtomicLongMap.create()`, and then the second thread is scheduled. Such thread will also create its own local map. `putIfAbsent()` is atomic, hence one of the threads will return null, while the second will return the map put by the first. In the latter case, you're throwing away the map that was instantiated by this thread, and using the one returned instead. Looks good to me.